# Make list of functions with lapply

Tags: r, list, function, auto-generate

Is there any way to make the following list of functions using lapply?  Below, I make a list named "long" the long way.  I would like to simplify the code using lapply (or a for loop) but neither seems to work.  Thank you.

```
#This works as expected
long <- list(function(x) x <- within(x, DATE <- as.Date("2013-01-01")),
             function(x) x <- within(x, DATE <- as.Date("2014-01-01")),
             function(x) x <- within(x, DATE <- as.Date("2015-01-01")))

#This does not work
long <- lapply(2013:2015, function(i) x <- within(x, DATE <- as.Date(paste(i, "01", "01", sep = "-"))))

#This does not work
for (i in 2013:2015) long <- list(function(x) x <- within(x, DATE <- as.Date(paste(i, "01", "01", sep = "-"))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the simplest method is to add another `function`.

```
long <- lapply(2013:2015,
              function(i) function(x) {
                           x <- within(x, DATE <- as.Date(paste(i, "01", "01", sep = "-")))})
```

Check that the elements are functions

```
typeof(long[[1]])
[1] "closure"
```

Test it

```
# empty list, x
x <- list()
x <- long[[1]](x)
x
$DATE
[1] "2013-01-01"
```

---

As @Roland mentions in the comments, it would be safer to force the evaluation of the i argument.

```
long <- lapply(2013:2015, function(i) {
                            force(i);
                            function(x) x <- within(x,
                                            DATE <- as.Date(paste(i, "01", "01", sep = "-")))
                           })
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not produce the same result as my example.

Comment: @user1491868 The only difference is that the value of `i` is stored in the functions' enclosing environment. They can be used and give the same return values as your example.

Comment: @lmo I guess I'm old-fashioned but I would `force(i)`.

Comment: You could say that the difference between this answer and mine is that this is a "run-time" solution to getting the date, whereas mine is "compile-time".

Comment: @HongOoi A nice analogy, but it implies more of a performance difference when using these functions than I'd expect.

Answer (score 3):

With some `bquote` magic:

```
dates <- c("2013-01-01", "2014-01-01", "2015-01-01")

lapply(dates, function(d) eval(bquote(function(x) within(x, DATE <- as.Date(.(d))))))

#[[1]]
#function (x) 
#within(x, DATE <- as.Date("2013-01-01"))
#<environment: 0x000002b1815ba450>
#
#[[2]]
#function (x) 
#within(x, DATE <- as.Date("2014-01-01"))
#<environment: 0x000002b1815ae320>
#
#[[3]]
#function (x) 
#within(x, DATE <- as.Date("2015-01-01"))
#<environment: 0x000002b1815a1520>
```

(The assignment `x <- within(...)` is superfluous inside the function.)

Explanation: `bquote` creates an *unevaluated* expression object, with symbols marked out by `.(*)` replaced by their values. `eval` then evaluates the expression.

In this case, `bquote` creates a call to generate a function using `function(x) ...` with the specific date inserted, so if `d` has the value `"2013-01-01"`, then `bquote(function(x) ... as.Date(.(d))` results in the *unevaluated* expression `function(x) ... as.Date("2013-01-01")`. When you call `eval` on this, the result is a function object containing your desired function body.

See `?eval` and `?bquote` for more details.

Comment: This list is identical to my example but for the <environment: 0x000002b1815ae320> piece.

Comment: That's fine, that's the environment created by `lapply`. It will still work.

Comment: Thank you this is very good.  If you get a moment to explain what "eval" and "bquote" are doing that would be great.

Comment: See `?eval` and `?bquote`. The latter creates an unevaluated expression object, with symbols marked out by `.(*)` replaced by their values. The former then evaluates the expression. In this case, `bquote` creates a call to generate a function using `function(x) ...` with the specific date inserted.

Comment: Continuing: if `d` has the value `"2013-01-01"`, then `bquote(function(x) ... as.Date(.(d))` results in the unevaluated expression `function(x) ... as.Date("2013-01-01")`. When you call `eval` on this, the result is a function object containing your desired function body.